# Link to a different view mode from entity reference

Tags: entities

Created a entity reference field i CONTENT A and linking it to CONTENT TYPE B. It works fine and takes me to the linked FULL CONTENT. Is it possible to link it to a different view mode like a TEASER or other view mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [View Mode Page](http://drupal.org/project/view_mode_page) before, and it might do the trick for you. Basically assign a view mode for a content type given a URL pattern. Pretty neat.

Answer (score 1):

a link: `/some/somthing/here` is just a link. It resolves to a resource on Drupal (see `hook_menu`).

A node by default lives at the url `node/NID` which shows the `full` view mode. You need [Views](http://www.drupal.org/project/views), a [Context](http://www.drupal.org/project/context), a [Panel](http://www.drupal.org/project/panels) -- and a different url then `node/NID` to show a different view mode.

So yes ... you can make a different url to show a teaser. How you make the url is up to you.